# get vega/vega-lite spec after programmatic data updates via views

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I made changes to a vega-lite chart via `view.change` ([here](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/)), then I want to export the vega-spec. I checked how the buttons in vega-embed does it ([code](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed/blob/154c0476d33a4cd398c53ad680db0df1822ca8f3/src/embed.ts)) but realized that it just references the original spec. I need the vega spec after. Any one has any ideas how? The `view` APIs don't see to give a, "get spec" functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View updates do not change the spec but only the state of the dataflow. Use `view.getState` to get the state. More at https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_getState.